# req.params returns undefiened

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get back the ID from the params but it keeps sending back undefiened, what would be the problem here and how can i solve it ?

this is the route:

```
app.delete(`${api_version}/delete-branch/:id`, verifyToken, branches.deleteBranch)
```

this is the controller:

```
exports.deleteBranch = (req, result) => {
const {branch_id}  = req.params
console.log(branch_id) // => returns undefined
if(branch_id === undefined) {
    result.status(404).send({
        message: 'This branch does not exist',
        statusCode: 404
    })
} else {
    // console.log(req.params)
    Branches.deleteBranch(branch_id, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            result.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            })
        } else { 
            result.status(200).send({
                message: 'Branch deleted successfully',
                statusCode: 200,
                data
            })
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: const {id} = req.params will be the correct statement since you are writing it like /:id so the params will contain id, if you want to name it as branch_id you need to change the route to /:branch_id

Comment: Can you please post how you define your other routes?

Comment: @Naeem yes i tried that but im not getting any response from postman, i end up with "Could not get response"

Comment: @Pytth its all the same way i just change the method if its a get, post, delete or patch, the other routes are working just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to destruct `req.params` like this:

`const {id} = req.params`
instead of:
`const {branch_id}  = req.params`

Or either defined the route as follow:
`` app.delete(`${api_version}/delete-branch/:branch_id`, verifyToken, branches.deleteBranch) ``
and then destruct `const {branch_id}  = req.params`;

Comment: okay i did that, now postman does not send a response, it gets stuck at "sending request", then "Could not get response"

Comment: So i guess something is wrong with deleteBranch method.

Comment: okay got it, you were right i had a problem in the method, Thank you!